# two dependency that need different version of React dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, reactjs, npm

my project is contains two dependency that need different version of React dependency, 
when i set the react version ^15.0.0, the first dependency (input-moment) showing warning message at the browser console like the message below

> Warning: Unknown props `i`, `w` on  tag. Remove these props from the element.

but when i set the react version ^0.14.0, the second dependency (recharts) showing this warning message on the console

> Warning: You are manually calling a React.PropTypes validation function for the `allowDecimals` prop on `XAxis`. This is deprecated and will not work in production with the next major version. You may be seeing this warning due to a third-party PropTypes library.

please help, how to solve this?

[-> npm input-moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/input-moment)

[-> npm recharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recharts)

Comment: Can you submit a PR to the library to support v15?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, both list peer dependencies of React 14 or 15.

- https://github.com/recharts/recharts/blob/master/package.json
- https://github.com/wangzuo/input-moment/blob/master/package.json

So both libraries contain bugs and an issue should be raised with them on github. If a package lists v15 as a peer, and doesn't work with said version I consider that a bug.

Just did a search on their issue tracker:

- https://github.com/wangzuo/input-moment/issues/36